# Is it significant that the eyes being reflective are proof that a Soul is inside in "The Host"?

Tags: stephenie-meyer, the-host

The eyes being reflective are proof that a Soul is inside of the body in *The Host*, and is used as verification by both Souls and humans:

> "Look, look, look!" he says. He pulls a small cylinder from his hip pocket and twists the top. A beam of light shoots out the end.
>   He turns the flashlight on his face.
>   The light makes his skin yellow. It shows the prominent cheekbones beside a long thin nose and a sharply squared-off jaw. His lips are stretched in a grin, but I can see that they are full, for a man. His eyebrows and lashes are bleached out from the sun.
>   But that's not what he's showing me.
>   His eyes, clear liquid sienna in the illumination, shine with no more than human reflection. He bounces the light between left and right.
>   <sub>*The Host*, chapter 4 (page 35)</sub>

This seems like it should have some sort of significance - the phrase '[the eyes are windows to the soul](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_eyes_are_the_window_to_the_soul)' comes to mind - but I don't know what the significance could be. So:

**Is there a significance to this? If so, what?**

Comment: Possibly the fact that, with a few exceptions, the souls are good (in a twisted way). They believe they are helping their hosts and after all to a large degree they do... So the shining is like a halo?